# discord.py on_message cancel when new command is executed

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

How can I cancel my on_message event when I execute another command? My code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = message.author
    def check(m):
        return m.channel == message.channel and m.author != client.user

    if message.content.startswith("!order"):
        await channel.send("in game name")
        in_game_name = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

        await channel.send("in game ID")
        in_game_ID = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

    else:
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cancel" the event?

Comment: when I execute another command, right now, it sends the rest of the messages and then executes the other command, how can I avoid that and simply execute the new command?

Comment: I don't get it... You only have one command being listened to, and that is 'order'

Comment: Are you also using `@client.command`s?

Comment: I have more, I won't put 1200 lines of code here

Comment: Yes, I'm also using `@client.command()`

Answer (score 1):

on_message should realistically only be reserved for events that require an on_message event (say if you are writing an auto-moderation feature).

For commands, you should be using the `@client.command` or `@bot.command` decorators before a function. [Here](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html) is the usage for commands. Here are a few reasons on why you should use commands (taken directly from the ?tag commands on the discord.py discord):

- Prevents spaghetti code

  - Better performance
  - Easy handling and processing of command arguments
  - Argument type converters
  - Easy sub commands
  - Command cooldowns
  - Built-in help function
  - Easy prefix management
  - Command checks, for controlling when they're to be invoked
  - Ability to add command modules via extensions/cogs
  - Still able to do everything you can do with `Client`

If you have any questions, feel free to comment on this answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `on_message` event inside a cog. That way, the `on_message` event (or any other event/command) will only be triggered when the cog is active.

```
class Foo(commands.Cog):

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        # Do something
```

To register the cog (activate):

```
bot.add_cog(Foo(bot))
```

To remove the cog (deactivate):

```
bot.remove_cog('Foo')
```

[Link to cog doc](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html#cogs)